# Remove section/subsection from one of two TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I have two TOC in my document, one for the hole document ("main" TOC) and one for only the appendix. I want to remove all sections and subsections from appendix in the "main" TOC but not in the TOC for appendix. Is this possible without re-coding everything. I have tied using:

```
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egrou
```

with

```
\tocless\section{section name}
```

But with this i lose the subsection in the smaller TOC for the appendix.
I have tried different placement of the command above but that does't work.

This is the code I have now that generate my two TOC:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\begin{document}   

%first TOC at beginning of document:

\tableofcontents

%Second TOC just before Appendix for the Appendix:

\appendix\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}        
\startcontents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Appendix}
\printcontents{}{0}{%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%
\tableofcontents}
```

Anybody know how to solve this? J

Comment: Why not use the starred version of section* subsection* in the documents appendix, which does not give a TOC entry?

Comment: This does not solve my problem what i can see. If i use section* and subsection* these disappears from both TOC's. I want them to remain in the TOC for the appendix but not in the main TOC...

Comment: Have you ever used the `minitoc` package? there are different tocdepth versus minitocdepth possible.

Comment: See the manual, sec. 4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution.

Use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}    %for main toc
\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}    %for appendix toc
```

---

**Update** because of expansion (issue with `calc` package see comments) it's better to use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\addtocontents{ptc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
```

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

%Second TOC just before Appendix for the Appendix:
\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\startcontents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Appendix}
\printcontents{}{0}{%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%
\tableofcontents}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

**main toc**

> [image]

**Appendix toc**

> [image]

Comment: Big thanks for this, but i cant get it to work as above. When using:   \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} and
\addtocontents{ptc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}} i get warnings. If i skip the TOC for the appendix part and only use \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} just after \appendix i still get warnings. Is there a usepackage i'm missing, because after this command logical this should work and only show appendix heading on level 0 (chapter?) in the main TOC.

Comment: I also had \stopcontents at the end of the document, is that needed?

Comment: This is the two warnings i get: ! Undefined control sequence.\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next{\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f... ...ocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} and ! Undefined control sequence.\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next ...ocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

Comment: in this case (end of document) `\stopcontents` is optional.

Comment: can you please add a minimal example of code that produce the issue?

Comment: As I can see it seems to be a problem with `calc` package please try with `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\addtocontents{ptc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}`